# How to config continous deployment from BamBoo to CloudControl

Tags: php, ssh, bamboo, cloudcontrol

I'm configuring my project so that after building and testing phase, the project will be automatically deployed to CloudControl.
However, I'm struggling with the configuration

Since my web app written in php so I have to choose SSH as deployment method.

The following is my configuration (it doesn't work), host/port are getting by running "bin/ip addr" in the remote server

Host: 10.36.49.48

Port: 26

SSH command: cctrlapp ssh://myapp@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git push

How can I fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push your code by either running

```
cctrlapp myapp/mydeployment push
```

or

```
git add remote cctrl ssh://myapp@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git
git push cctrl mydeployment
```

The deploy itself (which is seperate from pushing the code) is done by

```
cctrlapp myapp/mydeployment deploy
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I want to push my web app from my remote server to cloudcontrol using ssh. But I couldn't find out the host and port number of cloudcontrol.
I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: The host and port number are cloudcontrolled.com:22. You can only push your code using git or bazaar (both are using ssh), either by calling git/bzr directly or by using cctrlapp.